# Writing a file into the Downloads folder with UWP goes into Isolated Storage?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, isolatedstorage

I need to create a file in the downloads folder for a UWA on Windows 10 and copy the content of an existing file into it. I use the following code:

```
StorageFile cleanFile = await Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync(cleanFileName);

await file.CopyAndReplaceAsync(cleanFile);
```

This works ok, but the folder the file is stored is this:

```
C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\e15e6523-22b7-4188-9ccf-8a93789aa8ef_t8q2xprhyg9dt!App\WordComment-clean.docx
```

I assume this is some type of Isolated Storage. But really, that is not what I need. Since the user can't see the file like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**From MSDN:**

> User’s Downloads folder. The folder where downloaded files are saved by default.
>
> By default, your app can only access files and folders in the user's Downloads folder that your app created. **However, you can gain access to files and folders in the user's Downloads folder by calling a file picker** (FileOpenPicker or FolderPicker) so that users can navigate and pick files or folders for your app to access.

If you don't use a file picker, you are saving the file in your app folder in Downloads.

[Souce](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

### Using the Download folder

For using the download folder, the user needs to select the download folder manually.

```
FolderPicker picker = new FolderPicker { SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads };
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    StorageFolder folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    if (folder != null) {
           await folder.CreateFileAsync("Hello1.txt");  
    }
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Not really unfortunately. I am creating a file in the download folder with: DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync. But that file goes into this weird isolated storage folder. E.g. not visible to the user.

Comment: When I run `StorageFile cleanFile = await Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("hello.txt");` it creates a file hello.txt in C:\Users\myUser\Downloads\TestUniversal , TestUniversal is the name of my app, I thought that you want to save the file in the Downloads folder and not in subfolder with the app name.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. Save it directly into the Downloads folder. In my case it saves it into C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\e15e6523- .... .._t8q2xprhyg9dt!App\WordComment-clean.docx

Comment: Ok, time to look stupid. It indeed stored the files in Downloads/CleanOfficeFiles (which is the name of the app). Was not even looking for that. But is there a way to put them into the root Downloads folder?

Comment: @Remy the user needs to manually select the download folder, I just added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
      await file.CopyAndReplaceAsync(cleanFile);
      await file.RenameAsync("the name you want")