# UWP can write to files of many types in Downloads folder but cannot do the same for SQLite db file

Tags: c#, uwp, system.data.sqlite

**Environment**: [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core/), [SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_winsqlite3 2.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_winsqlite3/2.0.1?_src=template), `Windows-10`, `VS2019- ver16.3.6`

Following code works in my `UWP` app to create a a file in [Downloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.downloadsfolder) folder in `Windows 10`, and also can write to that file. But, as shown in the `second code block` below, when I do the same by creating an `SQLite` file, say, `sqliteSample.db` in the `Downloads` folder and then try to open that db it gives me the error shown below:

**Following code snippet works for creating and writing to a file in Downloads folder**:

```
StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt");

Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker
{
    SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Downloads
};
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

StorageFolder oPickedFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if (oPickedFolder != null)
{
    //Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder (including other sub-folder contents)
    Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", oPickedFolder);
    string sSQLDbPath = Path.Combine(oPickedFolder.Path, "sample.txt");
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile = await oPickedFolder.GetFileAsync("sample.txt");
    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, "Swift as a shadow");
}
```

**Following code snippet successfully creates `sqliteSample.db` file in Downloads folder, but gives error shown below when trying to open it**:

**Remarks**: Below error occurs at line `db.Open();` of the following code. I've verified in the debug mode in `VS2019` that the variable `sSQLDbPath` has the correct path and when I manually copy/paste that path to the Windows explorer, I can see the `sqliteSample.db` file in the same subfolder of the Downloads folder that also has the `sample.txt` file created from the above code and that works without error.

> > SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.

```
StorageFile file = await Windows.Storage.DownloadsFolder.CreateFileAsync("sqliteSample.db");

Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker folderPicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker
{
    SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Downloads
};
folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".db");

StorageFolder oPickedFolder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
if (oPickedFolder != null)
{
    //Application now has read/write access to all contents in the picked folder (including other sub-folder contents)
    Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", oPickedFolder);

string sSQLDbPath = Path.Combine(oPickedFolder.Path, "sqliteSample.db");
using (SqliteConnection db = new SqliteConnection($"Filename={sSQLDbPath}"))
{
    db.Open();

    String tableCommand = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT " +
        "EXISTS MyTable (Primary_Key INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        "Text_Entry NVARCHAR(2048) NULL)";

    SqliteCommand createTable = new SqliteCommand(tableCommand, db);

    createTable.ExecuteReader();

}
}
```

From [File and folder permissions in the Downloads folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.downloadsfolder#file-and-folder-permissions-in-the-downloads-folder):

> The user can give another app access to your
>   file by selecting the file from the file picker. Your app can also use
>   the file picker to get access to the files in the Downloads folder
>   that it didn't create.
>
> Capabilities are not needed to create or access files in the Downloads
>   folder.

**NOTE**: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36765672/1232087) did not help either.

Answer (score 1):

Short story: SQLite can't see the downloads folder. It can only write to databases in the app's ApplicationData folders.

Longer explanation: Your app has full access only to a few locations (i.e. read only to its install folder and read-write to its application data). Other locations (libraries granted via capabilities, picked files or folders, downloads directory) are granted access by the file broker. The app uses this access via functions that adhere to the UWP app security model such as the Windows.Storage classes (as demonstrated in your working code to create the database) and [CreateFileFromApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/mt846585(v=vs.85)).

SQLite's default implementation doesn't use any of these methods that use the brokered file access, so ApplicationData is the only read-write location that the default SQLite implementation can use without modification. You can grant the app access elsewhere (e.g. with the broadFileSystemAccess capability), but SQLite doesn't by default use the right API to make use of that access.

In theory you could modify SQLite to use these API (probably in a SQLite virtual file system), but I'm not aware of any actual implementations which have done so.